# Zyxel G-202 Wireless USB adapter on Kali

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I'm new to Linux and I want to use an old [Zyxel G-202](https://download.zyxel.com/G-202/datasheet/G-202_6.pdf) wireless adapter of mine  for penetration testing.

However, since this adapter was compatible with Windows XP, it is not being recognized now. I tried to install *ndiswrapper* but apparently it is meant for Ubuntu. Any ideas?

Comment: It uses the ZyDAS ZD1211 https://wiki.debian.org/zd1211rw chipset so you would follow its instructions. I have not found Kali-specific instructions, but perhaps you will find them at https://forums.kali.org/

Comment: The [firmware-zd1211](http://http.kali.org/pool/non-free/z/zd1211-firmware/) package exists in the non-free repo. A simple `apt install firmware-zd1211` should do it.

Comment: Thank you @Freddy and @K7AAY! I installed the firmware that you have specified and it works!

Comment: @FrenkFrenk Please write a short [self-answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and accept it after two days. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after some consultation, I found the answer for my question!

It turns out that there is a Debian firmware for Zyxel G-202, which uses a ZyDAS ZD1211 chipset.

To install it, you enter `apt install firmware-zd1211` under terminal.

For more information click [here](http://http.kali.org/pool/non-free/z/zd1211-firmware/) and [here](https://wiki.debian.org/zd1211rw).

Huge thanks to @Freddy and @K7AAY!